# MySQL - How to alter part of a table element while keeping part of it the same

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database table (let's call it MyTable). In this database there is a column of paths for a file, with paths such as "C:/Users/me/test.txt". I can find table objects with a given file like this:

```
select * from MyTable where path = "C:/Users/me/test.txt";
```

I also know how to get all objects whose paths are in a particular directory, like this:

```
select * from MyTable where path regexp "^C:/Users/me/.*$";
```

I have a new directory that all the files in the test folder was moved to, called newFolder, and I need to write a command to update the paths in the database table. For example, if the object's original path was saved in the database as "C:/Users/me/test.txt", I need the new value saved to be "C:/Users/newFolder/test.txt". I can figure out how to do it without the file name included (if just the path was present), but I'm not sure how to preserve the file name while updating the path. If anyone knows a way to do this I'd realy appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read about the [REPLACE() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)?

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET path = REPLACE(path, 'C:/Users/me/', 'C:/Users/newFolder/');
```